# define datetime and date formate globally in cakephp 2.x

Tags: date, cakephp-2.0, datetime-format

i am saving date in database in timestamp format. 
while displaying the date i want to show it in given format i.e. MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm.
will you please guide me where should i define the global variable and how to access that to show the date in MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm format while showing it on site.

Answer (score 0):

To format the timestamp value, you can use php's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

For example, in your views, you could use

`echo date("F j Y g:i",$foo['timestampColumn']);`

To abstract that logic, you can create a function and put it in your bootstrap.php

```
function myDateFormat($timestamp){
    return date("F j Y g:i",$timestamp);
}
```

Then in your views, use:

`echo myDateFormat($foo['timestampColumn'])`